# Soap PHP WSDL Error

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

```
$AgemniWebServices = new SoapClient("");
$theusername = "";
$password = "";
$companyName = "";
$theusernamee = "fltest";
$fname = "FTEST";
$lname = "LTEST";
$phone = "8888888888";
$zip = "12345";
$areaid = "1";

$keyVals = array(
    "Username" => "Username",
    "FName" => "FName",
    "LName" => "LName",
    "password" => "password"
);
$valVals = array(
    "Username" => $theusernamee, 
    "FName" => $fname, 
    "LName" => $lname, 
    "password" => "test"
);

$params = array(
    'strUsername' => $theusername, 
    'strPassword' => $password, 
    'strCompanyName' => $companyName, 
    'objecttype' => '10', 
    "keys"  => $keyVals, 
    "values" => $valVals
);

$resp = $AgemniWebServices->ValidateEntity($params);
$resp = $AgemniWebServices->CreateEntity($params);

var_dump($resp);
```

I receive error:

```
object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
    ["ValidateEntityResult"]=> object(SoapVar)#8(4) {
        ["enc_type"]=> int(0)
        ["enc_value"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (11) {
            ["status"]=> string(5) "Error"
            ["description"]=> string(23) "[Username] is required."
            ["errorNumber"]=> int(1)
            ["statusCode"]=> string(9) "Succeeded"
            ["xmlResult"]=> string(39) ""
            ["EntityValidated"]=> bool(false)
            ["EntityCreated"]=> bool(false)
            ["EntityUpdated"]=> bool(false)
            ["EntityIDCreated"]=> int(0)
            ["InvoiceIdCreated"]=> int(0)
            ["isloggedIn"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["enc_stype"]=> string(15) "ExceptionReport"
        ["enc_ns"]=> string(44) "http://tempuri.org/AgemniWebService/Service1"
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are they really expecting "Username" and not "username"? Is that supposed to be some BASIC auth? No WSDL? Man where to start... Do they have a REST API from this decade? Finally, work on formatting your question better, will get more attention.

Comment: http://www.agemni.com/AgemniWebservices/service1.asmx?WSDL

<s:element name="CreateEntity">
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="strUsername" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="strPassword" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="strCompanyName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="objecttype" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="keys" type="tns:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="values" type="tns:ArrayOfAnyType"/>

</s:element>

Comment: Web Service Protocol
The Web Service uses a SOAP protocol to exchange messages. The WSDL info can be located

Comment: The strUsername and strPassword is the auth, my keys and values are not being read I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is surely due to the fact that the data array structure is incorrect according to the WSDL. You should definitively use a WSDL to php generator which is nowadays very common. It helps structuring the request data and easily handle the response all with an OOP approach.

You should take a look to the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which could really help you deal with this SOAP Web Service.